# Tomcat no encuentra los recursos

Tags: java, angularjs, http, tomcat

Bueno tengo una aplicación con AngularJS que hace peticiones al API de `gitHub` como un ejemplo para aprender a usar AngularJS, pero el problema es que cuando meto la pagina con todas las dependencias en un `Dynamic Web Project` de Java (esto lo hago porque necesito usar servicios REST definidos con Jersey), y lo corro con `Tomcat 8.0.36`, me tira los siguientes errores en la dev console de Chrome (lo pruebo en Chrome porque en el navegador de `Eclipse` no tengo consola de desarrollador para tracear los errores).

La primera vez que intento entrar a `localhost:8080/MissingDog` pasa esto:
[image: Error Log]
Después muestra este log cuando sigo tratando de entrar:
[image: Error Log 2]
Este es el log si abro el index.html directamente desde una carpeta, sin meterlo dentro del Dynamic Web Project de Java:
[image: Error Log 3]

Les dejo mi arbol de directorios del proyecto de Java (`MascotaService.js` no esta implementado todavia, no hace nada):

[image: Directorie Tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las imágenes del error muestran la causa del problema, junto con la imagen de la estructura de tu proyecto. Tus recursos están dentro de la carpeta `WEB-INF`, la cual **no es visible por los navegadores**. Los servidores de aplicaciones en Java **no muestran** el contenido de esta carpeta.

Para resolver tu problema, basta con mover los archivos de ubicación a fuera de la carpeta `WEB-INF`. La estructura de tu proyecto sería como sigue:

```
WebContent
- META-INF
- resources (aquí van tus recursos JS, CSS, etc)
  - css
  - fonts
  - images
  - js
  - lib
  - (otras carpetas...)
- WEB-INF
  + web.xml
  - (otros archivos y carpetas para la configuración de tu proyecto como web.xml)
```

Comment: Era eso nada más.... muchas gracias. Ya esta todo funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Solo una pequeña aclaración, los archivos de la carpeta web-inf si pueden ser accesados, solo paginas web(jsp,xhtml,html), pero para accesarlos archivos dentro de esta carpeta, se tiene que pasar por un controlador, no serán accesibles a través de una url, por lo cual es una buena practica por seguridad y sigue el patron MVC.

Saludos

Comment: Perdón @sibok666, pero no entendí del todo. ¿Solamente archivos `jsp`, `xhtml` y `html` son accesibles sin pasar por un controlador?

Comment: Al contrario, si los archivos están en la carpeta WEB INF, solo serán accesibles por medio de un controlador, en cuestiones de buenas practicas, en la carpeta web content, solo deberías tener un Index, que realice un redirect a una pagina en la carpeta WEB INF, todos los resources en la carpeta web content.

Comment: ¿Pero si necesito cargar los recursos cuando se cargue el index.html? Para poder usar un controlador necesitaría importar las librerías de AngularJS. @sibok666

Comment: Los recursos de tu app, deben ir fuera de la carpeta web-inf, tambien todo el contenido de tu aplicación en angular, debe ir fuera de la carpeta web inf, te recomiendo que intentes realizarlo y nos compartas una captura de pantalla de tus resultados, para que te pueda ayudar a configurar tu aplicación ;), y recuerda, si vas a utilizar angular con java, vas a tener un controlador de tu app en angular y en java tendras un controlador que va a recibir las peticiones de tu aplicación de angular

Comment: A ver si entendí bien jaja. Las dependencias que tenga mi aplicación deben ir fuera de la carpeta WEB-INF (como las librerías de `angular` y `bootstrap` por ejemplo) y todo el contenido que dependa de estas librerías también. ¿Esta bien eso? Yo ya moví todo afuera de la carpeta WEB-INF a una carpeta `resources` y ahí puse todo.

Comment: Las dependencias deben ir fuera del web inf si, las paginas html que usen las librerias pueden estar dentro o fuera del web inf, solo paginas html, jsps, en una aplicacion angular, todo lo de js va fuera de web inf, OK saludos